# how to sample from a data frame along with the original indexing?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe and would like to use `.sample(frac=0.1)` and create a subset of the dataset. However, I would like to have the original indexing maintained in the subset. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If need original index values just use your solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(10, 100)})
print (df.sample(frac=0.1))
     a
60  70
64  74
70  80
63  73
40  50
57  67
77  87
30  40
66  76
```

If need default index values add [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`:

```
print (df.sample(frac=0.1).reset_index(drop=True))
    a
0  87
1  92
2  47
3  81
4  68
5  75
6  14
7  80
8  34
```